# I can't extract tar.bz2 file: error message, .h file: permission denied

Tags: 12.10, drivers

I'm trying to extract `r8101-1.023.00.tar.bz2` file, it's a driver(Linux driver for kernel 3.x and 2.6.x and 2.4.x) from [Realtek.com][realtek]. The fact is I get an error message:

> error to open the file
>
> .../r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.h": permission denied".

Any ideas?

```
  [realtek]: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2
```

What I get after  `tar -xjvf r8101-1.023.00.tar.bz2`

```
r8101-1.023.00/

r8101-1.023.00/src/

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.h

tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.h: No se puede [It can't be] open: Permiso denegado [permission denied]

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.h

tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.h: No se puede open: Permiso denegado

r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101.h

tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101.h: No se puede open: Permiso denegado

r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101_n.c

tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101_n.c: No se puede open: Permiso denegado

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_ethtool.h

tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_ethtool.h: No se puede open: Permiso denegado

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.c

tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.c: No se puede open: Permiso denegado

r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile_linux24x

tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile_linux24x: No se puede open: Permiso denegado

r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile

tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile: No se puede open: Permiso denegado

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.c

tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.c: No se puede open: Permiso denegado

r8101-1.023.00/autorun.sh

r8101-1.023.00/readme

r8101-1.023.00/Makefile

tar: Saliendo con fallos debido a errores anteriores [Exiting with failure due to previous errors]

What I get with sudo tar -xjvf r8101-1.023.00.tar.bz2

r8101-1.023.00/
 
r8101-1.023.00/src/

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.h

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.h

r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101.h

r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101_n.c

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_ethtool.h

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.c

r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile_linux24x

r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile

r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.c

r8101-1.023.00/autorun.sh

r8101-1.023.00/readme

r8101-1.023.00/Makefile
```

Comment: Have you tried to open it as root?

Comment: @CMDann I'm sorry, I a beginner, how could I open it as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the **r8101-1.023.00.tar.bz2** to your home folder, open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and copy and paste this command:

```
tar -xjvf r8101-1.023.00.tar.bz2
```

The graphical Archive Manager gave me the same permission error, but this worked for me even without `sudo`.

Comment: I get this                                                    tar (child): r8101-1.023.00.tar.bz2: No se puede [it can't] open: [file or directory does not exist] No existe el archivo o el directorio
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @user134910 Did you save the file to your **home** (/home/YOURUSERNAME) folder? Either way, your terminal is not opened in same folder where the file is and thus the command will not find the file. Ctrl+Alt+T by default opens the terminal in the home folder. :)

Comment: inicially I downloaded to Downloads folder but I changed to home folder since I saw your answer. I did what you say in the previous comment and I get the same message @pileofrocks

Comment: OK do it (I downloaded again in home folder)! But I don't how follow... @pileofrocks

Comment: @ntrpris Just open the terminal and try to command again then. If you write `ls` in the terminal, do you see the file listed?

Comment: r8101-1.023.00/
r8101-1.023.00/src/
r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.h
tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.h: No se puede [It can't be] open: Permiso denegado [permission denied]
r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.h
tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.h: No se puede open: Permiso denegado
r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101.h
tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101.h: No se puede open: Permiso denegado
r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101_n.c
tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/r8101_n.c: No se puede open: Permiso denegado
r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_ethtool.h
tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_ethtool.h: No se puede open: Permiso denegado

Comment: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.c
tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtl_eeprom.c: No se puede open: Permiso denegado
r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile_linux24x
tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile_linux24x: No se puede open: Permiso denegado
r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile
tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/Makefile: No se puede open: Permiso denegado
r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.c
tar: r8101-1.023.00/src/rtltool.c: No se puede open: Permiso denegado
r8101-1.023.00/autorun.sh
r8101-1.023.00/readme
r8101-1.023.00/Makefile
tar: Saliendo con fallos debido a errores anteriores [Exiting with failure due to previous errors]

Comment: before I didn't get these errors but I typed something wrong because I don't how use the terminal trying to advance and since then I get these errors. I downloaded the file again due to the errors but still I get them. forgive the mess, i edit my question so you can see clearer @pileofrocks

Comment: @ntrpris Any difference if you add `sudo` before the command? (Complete command being `sudo tar -xjvf r8101-1.023.00.tar.bz2`)

Comment: oh yes i'm sorry @pileofrocks , and when i write ls in the terminal i get r8101-1.023.00.tar.bz2 written in red

Comment: at this point point i think i'm going crazy, before i think i didn't get anything with sudo... XD but now i get the message written before, without the errors! @pileofrocks

Answer (score 1):

Try elevating your privileges by either entering root through the command line. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to launch the terminal.

```
su -
<root password>

tar -zxvf {file.tar.gz}
```

Or use `sudo`

```
sudo tar -zxvf {file.tar.gz}
```

Where `{file.tar.gz}` is the path to your file

Comment: it doesn't work @CMDann

Comment: what i get using sudo:                                           gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: I believe this is a an issue with the compressed file then, you may have to report it to the author..

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is quite late for the OP, but maybe this will help someone else.

I downloaded the exact same file and got the exact same errors, and, being time-pressed, for the life of me I too couldn't manage to uncompress it either via command line or graphical interface.

So I took a very inelegant approach. I started Nautilus (which is the name of Graphical File Manager) as root, and this way I was finally able to uncompress this file, without any warnings.

```
gksudo nautilus
```

A new window with root privileges will open, use it to navigate to where the file is and uncompress it.