# Can't extract in partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions

I have a data partition with ntfs filesystem. But when I want extract a file in that partition I get permission errors like:

[image]

`ntfs3-g` is installed and I ran on terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/ntfs/
```

without results. With `sudo tar -x` I haven't got problems, but It is boring this issue. I don't want move the file on my home folder like in this [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260791/i-cant-extract-tar-bz2-file-error-message-h-file-permission-denied). How can I solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Answer (score 0):

I solved reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92863/mount-ntfs-partition-at-startup-with-non-root-user-as-owner/517223#517223) discussion. Changing my `fstab` file from

```
/dev/sda3    /media/ntfs ntfs-3g silent,noatime,discard,umask=000,locale=it_IT.utf8 0 0
```

to

```
 /dev/sda3    /media/ntfs ntfs-3g exec,permissions,auto,silent,noatime,discard,umask=000,locale=it_IT.utf8 0 0
```

I added `exec,permissions,auto`